# Query Parameters are not visible in browser url, Lightning mode, when VisualForcePage is opened

Tags: visualforce, lightning, opencti, softphone

Why the query parameters are not visible in browser tab, when I'm using Lightning mode?
For example, I'm using the searchAndScreenPop method with pop to VisualForce match. 
I'm sending the following queryParams: ?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3

In Salesforce Classic, the opened url looks like this: 
https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/SearchPageView?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3

In Salesforce Lightning, the opened url looks like this: 
https://eu6.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?source=aloha#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YWxvaGFQYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJ2YWx1ZXMiOnsiYWRkcmVzcyI6Ii9hcGV4L1NlYXJjaFBhZ2VWaWV3P0FOST00MDA2OCZETklTPTQwMDY1JnZmUmV0VVJMSW5TRlg9aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZldTYubGlnaHRuaW5nLmZvcmNlLmNvbSUyRm9uZSUyRm9uZS5hcHAlM0Zzb3VyY2UlM0RhbG9oYSUyMyUyRnNPYmplY3QlMkZBY2NvdW50JTJGbGlzdCUzRmZpbHRlck5hbWUlM0RSZWNlbnQlMjZhJTNBdCUzRDE0OTAzNTI1MDIxMTAiLCJoYXNIaXN0b3J5IjpmYWxzZX19LCJhOnQiOjE0OTAzNTI1MTIwNjN9

The query parameters are send to the Visual Force page in both cases. My only question is why they are not visible on the browser url. Are they encoded in lightning mode?

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning mode all the VF pages gets render inside Lightning container iframe,  which you can see easily with inspecting a page. And the url of outer Lightning container is in encoded form.

So in Lightning mode you can't visually see the actual VF page url with url params.

Please mark this as solved if your doubt is clear.